# Python object with dictionary attribute being appended to with each loop iteration rather than being garbage collected

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, garbage-collection

I have created an Game class which has a dictionary attribute of players as an attribute, which should have ~36 players in it.

I am iterating though a loop, creating a new instance of a Game object with each iteration and printing the contents of each player onto a csv file.

However, with each iteration although a new object is created, it seems that the player attribute is being appended to rather than being garbage collected.

```
sheet = open('playerGames.csv', 'w+')
gameNum = 2018020001

while gameNum < 2018020015:

    game = Game(gameNum)

    print(len(game.players), end=", ")

    for player in game.players:
        for stat in game.players[player]:
            sheet.write(str(game.players[player][stat]) + ",")
        sheet.write("\n")
    game = None

    gameNum = gameNum + 1
```

The print statement in the above should print a number about 36 each time however it outputs the following `36, 72, 108, 144, 163, 199, 217, 253, 289, 325, 361, 397, 433, 469`

Should the garbage collection not clear this up? I have added the `game = None` statement in hopes that the entire object gets collected, however that does not seem to work.

Comment: What does `Game(gameNum)` does? I mean what does the constructor do, how is the variable `players` assigned? Moreover how is players declared inside the `Game` class?

Comment: @DanielMesejo That is creating the object. The game number is given as a parameter and __inti__() pulls data from an API with this number to create the attributes. Unfortunately I cannot really post the code for the Game class.

Comment: @DanielMesejo players is declared at the top of the class as an empty dictionary ```players = dict()``` and then in the constructor the API fills the dictionary with playerID keys and another dictionary of stats for the player as a value for each key.

Comment: Can you share the code that fills the dictionary? My guess is that you are inserting new players each time you do `Game(gameNum)` try doing something like `players = dict()` inside the `__init__`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo That worked! seems like it's treating players as a static variable when it's declared outside the constructor. I don't do OOP in python that often, is there a way to declare non-static attributes outside of your constructor class in python, or is this just not done in python?

Also if you want to post your comment as a response I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: `game = None` is unnecessary; garbage collection will be triggered for the `Game` instance whether the next value of `name` is `None` or another `Game` instance, and there is likely little reason to worry about a single `Game` instance sitting around in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `players` is defined as a global variable, you need to reset in your constructor, something like this:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, n):
        players = dict()
```

Having a global variable is a bad practice in any language, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). If players is a property of the `Game` objects you should do instead:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.players = { }  # dictionary construction expression
```